# What is the equivalent SOAP API call to the command *S?

Tags: soap, sabre

We have an agent desktop application that runs against the current PNR/session in Sabre Red.  We're using Native API to interact with Sabre Red and we have a Sabre Red App.

If an agent begins to build a reservation/PNR and has NOT ended the current PNR, the data in *GetReservation.ReservationPNRB.POS.Source.PseudoCityCode* is empty.  We need to know what PCC (Pseudo City Code) the agent is working it.  Is there a way to 'get current context' (agent session) via SOAP API?  The equivalent Sabre command would be ***S**.  If not, I assume this value would be available within the Red App SDK and plug-in environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be the SabreCommandLLSRQ which can be used to use host commands but using soap.

Comment: Yeah, so... I knew that, but was looking for something structured so we didn't need to parse the response.  Unfortunately, your answer is what Sabre Support came back with as well.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm quite curious about how you build your system. typically, as a best practice, a middle-tier API is created between the front-end and the back end. this middle tier API is then in charge of calling Sabre API systems; using this strategy can allow the engineer to adding metadata on context change calls for the internal API, so this metadata can help to track sessions, so this can be an effective solution, and this strategy is a good backup in case Sabre changes the original API, so maintaining this middleware is simple and manageable.

Comment: @YitzhakB.Solórzano could you please have look at this sabre-related question? If you can help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74642466/login-failed-on-sabre-ota-hotelavailrq